# Regex Match first occurrence of price

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse an HTML document. I am trying to grab the price from a div and I need to use regex to get only part of the content.

I have the string

```
6.956.95
```

and I need to return just

```
6.95
```

another example, I have the string:

```
22.9522.95
```

and I just need

```
22.95
```

My regex skills are not great and I have been trying a lot of different approaches that have not worked. Thanks!

Comment: The best solution would be to use Nokogiri's `at` method to retrieve only one price to begin with.

Comment: When you ask a question like this, it's really important that you include all the necessary information, especially HTML examples showing what you are working with. This helps us to help you. Otherwise, we're shooting in the dark, trying to guess what you're working with as raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you'll always have a decimal:

```
^\d+\.\d{0,2}
```

That says select one or more digits from the front of your string, followed by a decimal, followed by up to 2 digits and it will ignore anything past that.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need 2 'decimals':

```
> "22.9522.95"[/^\d+\.\d{2}/]
=> "22.95"
```

I'm still curious about why you have price representations with 2 periods.

Comment: You need to escape the dot

Comment: Me too! for this particular site that I am scraping, the price is repeated within the div. No idea why they do it that way, but that is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you need any pattern consisting of 1 or more digits followed by a decimal followed by exactly two digits:

```
\d+\.\d\d
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works with anything:

```
"foobarfoobar"[/(.+)\1/,1]
#=> "foobar"
```